# SQL Developer source control option

Tags: sql, oracle

I have switched from Toad to Sql Developer and was just looking for certain features in SQL developer  which I really found beneficial in Toad.

It had a team coding viewer option which is nice to keep a check on the source codes and versioning, though it had nothing to do with subversion.

Do we have any such feature in SQL developer. How can we manage team coding in SQL developer?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer allows the source code control feature which can full fill your requirements, here are the steps:

## 1. First connect to oracle database(using sql developer) by providing following info:

username, password, hostname, port(1521 by default), sid (orcl by default)

## 2. Create a repository:

versioning>create local repository>give local folder for the repository path and also provide connection name that you have created in sql developer application.
Next, expand the subversion node in the versioning navigator.
Next, right click on connection and choose new remote directory and provide sql files then click on Ok.

## 3. Import the files to be versioned:

In the files navigator, select the directory where you unzipped the files from the prerequisites under the files tab.
Next, versioning > import files

## 4. veiw the files which you want to be versioned:

view> files> choose the file for inside the navigator> then click on Next.
Now, confirm that connection name is mapped to the local directory and select the node sql files, then click on Next.
Click Browse and select the directory where you unzipped the files from the Prerequisites as the source directory, then click Next.
in the filter page, click next.
In the Options page, deselect the Perform Checkout check box and click Next.
Review the options for the Import operation and click Finish.
In the Versioning Navigator, expand hr_orcl > SQLFiles.

Please follow the link for the details along with the pictorial reference: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/srccodexmlext/srccode_otn.htm

Thanks.

Comment: In addition SQL Developer is now on version 4 - it's highly unlikely that anyone is still using version 2 or would want to start using an old version.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the reminder, 2.1.x.x version was mentioned as this features was available since 2.1.

Comment: You might want to edit your answer then - it implies that it was ONLY available in versions 2.1 and prior :)

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial options such as Red Gate's [Source Control For Oracle](http://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/purchase/product/sourcecontrolfororacle) if your employer is willing to stump up some hard cash (and it is well worth the money IMO). But failing that, I've found another guide which is for SQL Developer 3 - it's probably not that different to Suresh's but it is specifically for 3 which is the version you are more likely to be using so I'll [include it here](http://orajavasolutions.wordpress.com/tag/integrate-svn-with-sql-developer/). The author seems to be anonymous, but kudos to them for writing it up. I haven't been able to find a guide for version 4 and I haven't used it yet so I can't say if it's changed much.

The essence of this guide is as follows. Note that I have omitted anything relating to setting up an SVN repo as that information is easily available elsewhere.

**Integrating SQL developer with SVN**

- In sql developer, choose, View > Team > Version Navigator
- In Version Navigator, right click on Subversion, and select New Repository Connection and Provide the following details:

  - Repository URL -> `http://ipaddress/svn-repos/project-repos`
  - Connection Name -> Any user defined name.
  - User Name -> User name of user who is allowed to login into the repository.
  - Password  -> Password of the above user.
- Click Test Read Access, to ensure that connection to repository was successful.

**Adding Files to repository.**

Initially the repository (project-repos) is empty. To add files to the repository follow the steps below.

- Choose View > Files. Files tab will appear in Sql developer.
- In the Files tab, expand My Computer and select the folder which contains the files to be added.
- Choose Versioning > Import Files. Follow the six steps of the import files wizard, by selecting destination(svn repository), source (your hard disk files), filters, options.In step 5 of the wizard (options step), check the “Perform Checkout” check box.
  Finally click Finish. All the files of the selected folder (step 2) will be imported to svn repository.
- In the versioning Navigator, select the connection name for the repository and click the refresh button. All the files that you have added will appear with their version number in brackets.

**Accessing the repository.**

Now the repository has been created and files have been imported to repository, other users will need to access the repository.

- Create the connection to repository as shown in section 1.
- In Version Navigator,expanding the connection name will show all the files imported in Section 2.
- Under the connection name select the folder containing the files.
- Right click the folder and select Check-out.
- Select the destination folder where you want the files to created on your hard drive.
- Click ok.
- Go to Files tab and click refresh.
- Expand the tree and look for the folder the you selected in Step 5. This folder will now contain all the files that you have exported from the repository to your hard drive.

**Making changes to files and committing changes to repository.**

Any user can make changes to files (files that he has checked out (exported) from repository in section 3 or he has added to repository in section 2).

- From the Files tab, go to the folder that you have imported/exported to/from the repository.
- Select the file to modify,by double-clicking.
- File will open in edit mode. Make the required changes and save it. After you save the file, an asterik(*) will appear near the name of file in Files tab.
- Right click the file/folder that contains modified files, and choose Versioning > Commit.
- In the dialog box, give your comments for the changes and click Ok. When the commit is successful, the version number of the file will increase by one. All the changes made are now saved in the repository and other users can take these changes as explained in next Section.

**Updating changes from the repository.**

If a file has been changed and committed by any other user, you can update your local file from the repository version of the file.

- In the Files tab, select the file/folder to update.
- Right click and choose Versioning > Update.
- In the dialog box, choose required options and click ok. Now the file on your hard drive is in sync with the repository file.

Comment: No probs. Hope we all helped you find something suitable! Nice to see someone taking source control for database objects seriously - plenty of people don't and it's always a mistake.

Comment: Hi Steve, Can you please tell me if I can have a schema drop down list embedded in a worksheet in  sql developer?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Do you mean like Intellisense in Visual Studio/SSMS? If so then SQL Developer already does that (although it's no less dense and annoying than any of it's rivals).

Comment: I have multiple schemas. Each of them has same table names. Now to read data of a certain table in schemas , i have to go to schema browser and select one. Then i need to find the object and look for my data in it. If i try doing the same in a workshheet i have to write schema name then table name to fetch the data. If a have a drop down in the worksheet itself to alter the schema , i can skip the schema name before every table name to fetch the data. I dont know if the language is clear to you :(

Comment: I think I know what you mean (going by memory - don't use Oracle in my current contract). I don't think it does exactly what you want but there is a drop down which changes the connection used by the worksheet, so if you set up a connection per schema (which you only need to do once) then you can use this drop down to change which schema you target. It's in the top right hand side of the worksheet if memory serves.